# Using Inhaler during fasting. Allowable or not?

Tags: fiqh, sawm

Does it cancel's my fast if I use an Inhaler as a means to pervent myself from getting sleepy?

Is it haram or is it allowable?

Answer (score -2):

It is said in Islamic Fiqh Council, p. 213.

> *Inhalers are allowed in fasting and do not break it, as long as they are used in the respiratory route, not the digestive.*

**However, any medication (including inhalers) should not be used except in necessity.**

Comment: What is the evidence from what you quoted that they are only to be used in extreme necessity?

Comment: The same book, Islamic Fiqh Council, It is said that any medication (including inhalers) should not be used except in necessity.

Comment: Then it is better that you add that to the quote

Comment: is *"pervent myself from getting sleepy"* counted as necessity? Would it cancel the fast if it isn't counted as a necessity?  The answer seems not to really answering the question,  it is rather quiet abstract now

Comment: The asker did not specify in his question why would he prevent himself from sleeping. Is it for work? for fun? I cannot assume if this is a necessity or not. So I guess your comment should be directed to the asker.